# stop SSH access with out port number

Tags: linux, ssh

I can access SSH with the IP address. But I need to configure it in a way without a certain port number one can not access.

so if anyone tries to access with `ssh root@<ip_address>` it should not work. But if any one try with `ssh root@<ip_address -p <port_number>` , it should work. How can I do that ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/955051 or https://serverfault.com/q/229277

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Just configure your ssh server daemon `sshd` to listen to another port, have a look at the `sshd_config` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about changing SSH server port.

Edit file: /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Change line:

```
#Port 22
```

To line:

```
Port 2222
```

# is a prefix for comments

Command to ssh to the server:

```
ssh root@<ip_address> -p 2222
```

Restart service (not sure wich distribution you are running):

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

or

```
service sshd restart
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

or
reboot server.